# curl response showing nothing using within php

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

i am trying to get data from a url using curl. i've made a recursive function for this. i get the data successfully , but the problem what i am facing is that when no result is found against curl call, then the page show me nothing, only a blank page is shown.. no error at all. i've used var_dump() too for testing the response. but found nothing.

here is my recursive function

```
function recursive_get_scrap($offset, $page_size, $urls, $original_array){

    ini_set('max_execution_time', 1800);
    $of_set = $offset;
    $pg_size = $page_size;

    $off_sets = 'offset='.$of_set.'&page_size='.$pg_size.'';
    $url = $urls.$off_sets;        

    $last_correct_array = $original_array;

    $ch1 = curl_init();
    // Disable SSL verification
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    // Will return the response, if false it print the response
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);        

    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    // Execute
    $result2 =  curl_exec($ch1);

    $info   =   curl_getinfo($ch1);

    if(curl_errno($ch1))
        {
            echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch1);
            //return $last_correct_array;
        }


    // Closing    
    curl_close($ch1);



   if(!$result2 || strlen(trim($result2)) == 0 || $result2 == false){

        echo 'no array'; 
    }

    if(isset($result2) && !empty($result2)){

        echo 'in recursive function <br>';
        $a1 = json_decode( $original_array, true );
            $a2 = json_decode( $result2, true );                


                $temp_array = array_merge_recursive($a1, $a2 );                   

                $last_correct_array = $temp_array;
                $offset += 100;
                $page_size = 100;

                recursive_get_scrap($offset, $page_size, $urls, json_encode($last_correct_array));                                                 
    }


}
```

now what i only want it that if noting is get against curl call then `no array` message should be displayed.

Comment: Which URL you experience problems with?

Comment: try to `var_dump()` $info

Comment: It is perfectly possible that you simply don't get any response body back and that is fine by curl...

Answer (score 0):

Use this option to `curl_setopt():`

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

This will make curl_exec return the data instead of outputting it.

To see if it was successful you can then check $result and also

```
curl_error().
```

Comment: i used it already. curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  you can see that in my code

Comment: can you please give your url